# Manual printed message in Cassandra

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cassandra, cql, datastax

I have two tables in Cassandra, one is accounts and another customer. Customer table exists... but in case if customer dose not exist. I want to get a message printed like this:

```
Customer does not exist.
```

Can I get this feature inside a query or have to use with Java command?

Please suggest the queries or any idea if you have.

Comment: You're going to have to do that client-side.  CQL does not have any provisions for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

CQL themselves doesn't provide any statements for such use case. I can offer to do with Java using InvalidQueryException:

```
try {
        ResultSet result = session.execute("SELECT * FROM Customer LIMIT 1");           
    }
    catch (InvalidQueryException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Table Customer does not exist");
        session.execute("CREATE TABLE ...");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Can you suggest me what if the customer table is already present but the customer registering in my application  has to be checked if that exist or not... what do I check it then....